# Custom Undo/Redo in WPF TextBox with proper caret-movement

Tags: wpf, textbox, undo-redo

I have implemented a custom Undo/Redo stack and Im trying to get it to work with the WPF TextBox.

I have turned off the built in Undo-mechanism and hooked up my custom Undo on Ctrl+Z. Everything works fine accept that the caret in the TextBox is always being moved to index 0 on every undo/redo. The question is how to solve this?

I have tried having a custom behaviour on the TextBox which listens to TextChanged and is localizing the last change in the text-string. But this only works unless you start typing the same letter several times in a row. The my method breaks down.

What I ideally want is some kind of behaviour that only makes actual changes to the TextBox.Text-property. As it is now it is updated completely for every Undo, even if its only the last entered letter that is removed. This is of course no suprise since it listens to the Text-property on my PresentationModel which is triggering PropertyChanged on Undo.

But wouldnt it be great if there was some more fine-detailed way of telling exactly what had changed with the property-value, that only one or a couple of letters where inserted/removed in the string value. Then the TextBox could change only that without having to refresh its entire Text-value. Is there any such way of telling the TextBox this allready or could it be possible to make a custom TextBox that behaved in this way? Then it would be possible to pinpoint the exact location for the new caret without having it go straight back to 0 for every propertychange-update!

Comment: Why not make your undo stack record the caret position, too?  Instead of a Stack<string> use Stack<KeyValuePair<string, int>>

Comment: I rather not put this kind of information in the undostack. The stack only records changes in domain-properties and it wouldnt look good if I put UI-data there as well. I need to have this behaviour in the UI-layer and per TextBox.